# How can I send parameters to deep links in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking

I've managed to set up a deep link on Flutter for my app (currently only on android), here is the intent filter in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file to set up the deep link (using example host name and prefix):

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/prefix"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This works, whenever I access **http://example.com/prefix** on my phone, it suggests to open my app.

Now, I want to be able to pass in parameters to the deep link, maybe a URL parameter like http://example.com/prefix?code=abc123. So I can read it from my Flutter app like `getParam('code')` returns `abc123` for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I suggest you read about [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package in flutter.

Comment: Thank you so much, been looking at so many articles that got me nowhere. Need to start looking into the docs more often. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more advance Deep linking experience with specific domain name, Google firebase has a great product named Dynamic links and it is free.

There is an official package for Flutter to use as [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links/install).

Dynamic Links eliminates DeepLink weaknesses. With Dynamic Links, you treat on all platforms such as Android, iOS and web in a similar way. It seamlessly transits users from your mobile website to the equivalent content within your app (if the user has not installed your app on her/his device, the content would be shown after app installation). Furthermore, you can see the log of a Dynamic Link in the Firebase console. Another feature is to find out where the user clicked on the link.[more info](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Dynamic Links sound interesting, will look into them.

Comment: Were you able to get data from clicked web link using Firebase dynamic links?

Comment: really stupid question, do you need to be using firebase db to use dynamic links or are they unrelated?

Comment: I think Firebase Dynamic Links is not useful for including parameters in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [go router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) for your deep linking needs. It can handle two kind of scenarios.

You can use ":" prefix to mark any segment as parameter. Define it in GoRoute like this:

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/search/:keyword',
  builder: (context, state) => const UserScreen(id:state.pathParameters['keyword']),
),
```

If you use classic parameters instead of segments, where you put ?query=keyword at the end of url, you can define GoRoute like this:

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/search',
  builder: (context, state) => const UsersScreen(filter: state.uri.queryParameters['keyword']),
),
```